# Notepad++ Select text within multiple tags

Tags: xml, notepad++, edit

hope someone can help. I have a pretty big XML file that needs tidying up. Basically some line breaks are present which we need to get rid of. There are roughly 19,000 "`<Location>`" tags with text between. Is there a way to have NPP search for all `<Location>` tags, select it up to the closing  tag and perform join lines? Join lines fixes the problem, but it's going to take all day checking each one.

EDIT: Sorry, don't think I explained it very well! So basically there are more tags present in this XML document, for example:

```
<AccomRef>
<Code>BT1</Code>
<Location>Sometimes the text in here has line breaks
like this</Location>
</AccomRef>
```

I guess ideally I need to keep the tags nice and tidy with breaks after each closing tag, but just ensure that all location text is joined without breaks. I tried CTRL+A > CTRL+J but that then makes the file incredibly hard to read! Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Plugin "XML Tools". You can install it with the Plugin Manager. It offers several options:

- linearize
- beautify with and without linebreaks

You could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, Lars - this seems to have worked. I tried the beautify with line breaks and so far I haven't seen any text with the line breaks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that each `<Location>` tag has a matching closing tag of `</Location>` like this:

```
<Location>something</Location>
<Location>another</Location>
<Location>and again</Location>
```

And you want to get to

```
<Location>something</Location><Location>another</Location><Location>and again</Location>
```

If so, go to the `Replace` dialog (Ctrl + H) and pick `Extended` in `Search Mode`.
Enter `</Location>\r\n` as the `Find` text and put in `</Location>` as the `Replace` text.

This will then replace each closing tag + line break with just the closing tag.

I'd try this out on a sample file before doing it on your actual data though!

Edit: Now that you've clarified your question, my answer doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars mentioned there is a plugin, and it is great. But as understand your problem you have deal with situation like this

```
<location>some location</location>
<location>some 
location2</location>
<location>some location3</location>
```

and want to have something like this

```
<location>some location</location>
<location>some location2</location>
<location>some location3</location>
```

And if this your problem, you could solve it in two moves:

1)by replacing `\r\n` with blanks

2)by replacing `</location>` with `</location>\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `(?=<Location>)([^\r\n]+)\R(?!<location>)`
Replace with: `$1`

Make sure that `Regular Expression` is checked then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>